# How to return an array from Firebase when a user's id matches the document uid

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I would like to know how to retrieve an array or urls from Firebase with a query that checks that the current user's id matches the document uid, and if so, it returns the array of url strings outlined in image below.

[image]

Comment: Do you use angularfire2 https://github.com/angular/angularfire2 or the "standard" web SDK https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I am using angularfire2

Comment: Hi, did you have time to look at the proposed solution below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With angularfire2 you can do as follows:

```
this.itemDoc = afs.doc<any>('/lists/432jk....');  //You know the "the current user's id", then you can build the document ref (i.e. path)
this.item = this.itemDoc.valueChanges();
this.item.subscribe(value => {
  const urlsArray = value.urls;
});
```

More details in the documentation: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md

---

Or you could use the native JavaScript SDK as follows:

```
var docRef = db.collection('lists').doc('/lists/432jk....');

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
         const urlsArray = doc.data().urls;
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```